# import the whole database using sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I understand that we have `--import-all-tables` for importing all tables.
But can we import the whole database using Sqoop so that the DB properties are also imported.

Comment: BigData's answer seems to line up with my Hadoop experience. What database properties are you trying to import? Are you trying to import these tables into a Hive DB? In my experience, the properites of traditional RDBMS DBs do not translate well to Hadoop/Hive DBs/Avro files, etc.

Comment: Can you share a use case on what exactly you are planning to import as a part of DB properties?

Answer (score 2):

We can't import DB properties using Sqoop, using SQOOP we can only import  data from DB to HDFS along with java, avro files(avro schema contains table schema but not db properties).